# Regex to block multiple items

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a form on a site that is collecting user details.  There was a fool submitting the form with a name like "Barneycok" from different IP addresses, so I learned how to block that name from going through on the form.

I learned a little regex, just enough to write this little piece:

```
if (preg_match('/\b(\w*arneycok)\b/', $FirstName)){
$error.= "<li><font face=arial><strong>Sorry, an error occured.  Please try again later.</strong><br><br>"; 
$errors=1;
}
```

The code has worked perfectly and I never got that name coming through anymore.  However, recently, someone is entering a string of numbers on the name field.

The string looks like this:

```
123456789
123498568
123477698
12346897w
```

If you notice, the first 4 characters are constant throughout.

So how do I add that in my regex above so that if the name starts with "1234", it will simply match that regex and give the user the error code?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Jaime

Comment: @jamine hope my code will help you out...

Comment: Hey Sahil... thank for your contribution.  The problem is that now Barneycok can submit again.  I need to simply "add" the 1234 to the regex so that it blocks that and Barneycok also.  Make sense?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match `$FirstName` which starts with `1234`. for matching a specific word like `Barneycok` you should use this `(b|B)arneycok`

**Regex:** `^\s*1234|\b(?:b|B)arneycok\b`

> **1.** `^\s*1234` starts with `1234` can contain spaces in starting
>
> **2.** `|` is like `or` condition,
>
> **3.** `\b(?:b|B)arneycok\b` matches the word which contains `barneycok` or `Barneycok`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784759)

```
if (preg_match('/^1234|\b(?:b|B)arneycok\b/i', $FirstName))
{
    $error.= "<li><font face=arial><strong>Sorry, an error occured.  Please try again later.</strong><br><br>";
    $errors = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahil... thanks for your input.  The problem is that this code takes off the "Barneycok", so I'll start getting that fool using that name again.  I want to add the other regex to the same sting if possible.  Sorry that I didn't clarify that.  :-)

Comment: @Jaime sorry to ask you again, can you clarify it once?

Comment: Yes, you know how the current code blocks if anyone tries to enter the name "Barneycok" on the First Name field.  I need that to stay there and the form should continue to block that.  All I need to do is add "1234" so that it blocks ALSO anyone entering "1234558j374" in the first name field.  So it should block either of them.  Make sense?

Comment: @Jaime I have did the same with the post, It will block `Barneycok` and any name starts with `12345`

Comment: Oh... cool! So the secret is in adding the pipe " | " in between the expressions. Nice.  Thanks for your help.  I'll go ahead and test it out.

Comment: @Jaime i want to make a bit careful while using this `(\w*arneycok)`, this can match all `a-z` ,`A-Z` or `0-9` or `_` which is not good you should use like this `(b|B)?arneycok`

Comment: Sahil... You are a wizard man!  Thanks for your awesome help!  I'll be asking another regex question in a few minutes.  I'm sure you'll know how to help me with that one too.  If you want of course.  :-)

Comment: Damn... I can onlly post once every 90 minutes, so I have to wait until I can post my next question.  Basically, I have a regex that validates phone numbers and looks like this: if (!preg_match('/^[0-9ext()+ -.:]{9,35}$/i', $Phone))  My question is, how can I also add to block when people enter "555-1212" or "5551212" on the form?

Comment: @Jaime not an issue friend... I will surely help you.. once you post a new question, i will there.. :)

Comment: Thanks man... Listen, I have to get some sleep and can't wait 50 minutes until I can post again.  I'll post it tomorrow.  I hope you're around when I do.  Take care and thanks again for your help.  You're awesome!

Comment: @Jaime I have posted an answer you can check it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will work.

```
^1234.*
```

Comment: Thank you... but how do I add it to the regex code above?  Would the line look like this?

    if (preg_match('/\b(\w*arneycok)^1234.*\b/', $FirstName)){

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of providing the best possible pattern to protect your site, I'd like to offer this:

```
/^\s*1234|barneycok/i
```

This will match a string that has `1234` as its first non-white characters as well as a string that contains the substring `barneycok` (case insensitively).

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/5igcuv/1)

You will notice that the pattern:

- omits the leading word boundary (letting it catch `abarneycok`),
- doesn't bother with a non-capturing group with a pipe between `B` and `b` (because it is pointless when using the `i` flag)
- omits the trailing word boundary (letting it catch `barneycoka`)
- uses the `i` flag so that `bArNeYcOk` is caught.

You can implement the pattern with:

```
if(preg_match('/^\s*1234|barneycok/i',$FirstName)){
    $error.="<li><font face=arial><strong>Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later.</strong><br><br>"; 
    $errors=1;
}
```

On SO, it is important that the very best answers are posted and awarded the green tick, because sub-optimal answers run the risk of performing poorly for the OP as well as teaching future SO readers bad practices / sloppy coding writing habits.  I hope you find this refinement helpful and informative.